# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() without a condition updates the last created document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a full AJAX client form, where, if the post does not contain the client ID, it would create a new MongoDB entry, and if there an ID, it would update the entry.

I am trying to use mongoose's findOneAndUpdate() like so:

```
exports.post = function ( req, res ) {
    var payload   = req.body,
        condition = payload._id ? { _id: payload._id } : null,
        query     = {}

    query[ payload.fieldName ] = payload.value

    Client.findAndUpdate(
        condition,
        query,
        { upsert: true },
        function ( err, client ) {
            var response = {
                success: true,
                message: null,
                client: client
            }

            if ( err ) {
                console.error( err )
                results.success = false
                results.message = err
            }

            res.json( response )    
        })
}
```

My problem is that, if the condition is null or {}, it will find the last created entry and update that one, rather than create a new entry,

How do I get to my desired behaviour? if else and use 2 different mongoose methods based on the ID availability?

Comment: Have you tried using `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, it's actually a typo up there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you query with null or empty document it will return list of all document, for example 
db.collection.find() equivalent to db.collection.find(null) and db.collection.find({})

just update `condition = payload._id ? { _id: payload._id } : null,`  line to

```
condition = payload._id ? { _id: payload._id } : {_id:{"$exists":false}},
```

Hope it will help